# R&S Spectrum Analyzer Voltage Measurement Error

Tags: measurement, error, spectrum-analyzer

I just got FPC1000 spectrum analyzer that goes from 5 kHz to 1 GHz. I didn't had any spectrum analyzer experiences before this one so everything is very new to me.

Among few things that I don't understand about it is also a significant error seen at SA when measuring a signal directly from function generator.

I applied 1,05Vpp/10kHz sine wave directly to input of SA (using BNC to crocodile connector cable since I don't have the real probe yet). 1,05Vpp approximately equals 4 dBm (power unit). But SA shows me exactly -2 dBm, which equals approximately 500 mVpp (which is approximately a factor of 2 smaller than the real value)!

Even if I set output function generator impedance to 50 Ohms, SA shows me 1.8 dBm, which is 760 mVpp.

Are the probes making an error? Or am I missing something here? I cannot find the solution for this case.

[image][image][image]

Comment: It looks like you should be using a 7mm coax cable to connect to the SA... using alligator clips to hook onto a precision connector would make a microwave test tech cringe. It's possible the uncontrolled impedance and cables you're losing are introducing loss at 10kHz, but without that being characterized it's hard to say.

Comment: That said, when you do get the correct cables, you _will_ need to set your function generator to a \$50\Omega\$ output impedance to get the correct reading, as otherwise it's likely looking to output to a high-Z input, and the SA will load the signal generator more than it expects.

Comment: @Shamtam How about if I would measure a few kOhm or few 10kOhm load in circuit with SA? Would there be a mismatch too? Or does always measured load has to be 50 Ohms?

Comment: Measure the channel power of your signal, or use a larger RBW

Comment: How does the generator's indicated Vout change as you switch in the 50 ohms?

Comment: Have you cross-checked the output of the function generator with an oscilloscope to verify the output voltage and (rough) frequency?

Comment: at 10kHz, you may be off the low frequency end of the SA's accuracy specification. Try something more sensible like 1MHz, or read the SA's level specification carefully. Note that you only get accuracy when all instruments are 50ohms input or output impedance. Cross check with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @isdi Yes, I did. Scope indicates that values shown by F.G. are true.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf The SA indicates that the value of 1,05Vpp equals 1.8 dBm at F.G.'s output impedance of 50 Ohms. Closer to real value but still not there.

Comment: @Neil_UK So, even if I would measure a signal in a circuit (lets say an amplifier), the SA would indicate a wrong value, unless the load to be measured would be exactly 50 Ohm? If so, then with SA I can only measure loads of 50 Ohms or so? Otherwise, it is pointless, because it would show me wrong value of measured signal?

Comment: @Keno yes, use the wrong impedance, get a wrong answer. A common trick that I often use is to have a 470 ohm resistor in series with a piece of 50 ohm coax. This creates an approximately 20dB pad, which effect on the answer is easy to take out mentally, and it presents a high enough impedance to an RF circuit under test  to cause it minimal error.

Comment: @Neil_UK Hmm, how do you get away with 470 Ohm resistor (500 Ohm for exactly 20 dB attenuation)? I mean, 470R could easily affect circuit conditions, right? For uninterruptible circuit conditions (where you measure your signal), the probe would have to be of very high impedance - but that would also result in a too high attenuation, and eventually SA wouldn't detect anything...

Comment: @Neil_UK A solution to that would probably be an active probe (DIY). For example, using op-amp - input to measuring probes, output to SA. But that would had much influence on GBW (I doubt I could make a circuit that would be relatively flat from few kHz to 1GHz). But Idea of using opamp to adjust measuring signal to SA's input specs is solid one, I would say.

Comment: If the source and load impedances are the same, you can get away with an L-pad attenuator that will match their impedance.  If the source / load impedances differ than you end up using a TEE or PI attuenuator configuration.  Commercial attenuators are geared to 50 or 75 ohm terminating (source/load) impedance, but you can roll your own if necessary.

Comment: @Keno forgive me for being somewhat amused at the way people ask questions on here, and then in the next comment give advice to the people with years of experience that answer them. Your faith in opamps is touching.

Comment: I like R&S datasheet (sheet 6) they're only willing fully spec the level uncertainty from 10MHz to 3GHz as 0.5dB typical, but less than 1.25dB (at a 95% confidence level).  As Neil said above, I'd go to a higher frequency (unless it's a typo they only spec level accuracy to 100KHz).  You could try changing the attenuation (on SA) to see if starts to match better at lower input levels.  For accurate readings point calibration or bolometer with filtering would be better.

Comment: @Neil_UK Well, your "way" of probing using 470Ohm resistor is not any better either. This is okay only for measuring of low ohmic loads....

Comment: @Keno Measured load has to be 50 Ohms? The SA _is_ a load, and it's measuring the power incident on its receiver. Forget about the function generator, what exactly is it you're trying to measure in reality?

Comment: @Shamtam Audio frequency amplifiers for start, later HF/VHF amplifiers. If I would ALWAYS measure 50 Ohm source/load, I would have no trouble with it. But that is mainly in VHF applications (50R inputs, 50 outputs, etc.). In LF range of frequencies that doesn't help me much since loads vary a lot and 50R input from SA would indicate wrong results. For every other applications and circuits which are not in VHF range, I would most probably need some kind of converter that converts high impedance to 50R (high impedance to measuring probes, 50R to SA). End of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your signal generator has a output impedance of 50 ohms, and your analyzer has an input impedance of 50 ohms, then you have a resulting voltage divider with ratio 1:2.

So the measured voltage amplitude on the crocodile connector will be 1/2 of the signal generator output voltage.